# jquery selector only chosing the first list element

Tags: jquery

Can someone find what my mistake is? I have the following html list

```
 <ul id="left-help-menu">
        <li><a href=#">My Library</a>
            <ul class="left-menu-sub">
                <li id="1">A</li>
                <li id="2">B</li>
                <li id="3">C</li>
                <li id="4">D</li>
                <li id="5">E</li>

            </ul>

        </li>
      </ul>
```

and the following jquery code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#left-help-menu li li a").click(function() {
    var vid = $("#left-help-menu li li").attr("id");
            });
   });
```

For some reason, this selector is only chosing the first li tag ( when I test it by pasting 'vid' on the page, it always gives me '1'). Why is this?

Comment: What do you expect? An array of every `id` attribute matched?

Comment: Please read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). *Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements*

Answer (score 1):

That's the way an `attr()` getter works. It works on the first matched element.

If you want an array of all matched `id` attributes...

```
var vid = $("#left-help-menu li li").map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
```

Comment: Oh, I realized my mistake, I really wanted to return the id on the $(this) selector. Now it works. Thanks.